# html: body content is showing above html background image

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to position the content of my body inside the background image, but all the content seems to be appearing above the image and I'm not sure why that is or how I can fix it. Any help would be great.

Here's a link to how it's appearing currently: http://oi59.tinypic.com/e5p4qh.jpg

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Create a blog</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/reset.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-offset-10 col-md-2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Login</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row text-center">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Sign up</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/tent.jpeg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: background images are always below the content

Comment: this should work fine, there must be something else interfering. DO you have a link to your site that you can post?